# Python import problem after docker packaging

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I can run it fine until docker packages it. However, after I do the docker packaging, running this docker container prompts me with an import error
If anyone can help me with my problem, I'd appreciate it!
Here's the directory structure

```
├── Dockerfile
├── app.py
├── detection
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── yolo_config.py
```

Here is yolo_config.py

```
class YoloConfig:
    args = {
        "ENV": "dev",
    }
```

Here is app.py

```
from detection.yolo_config import YoloConfig
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(YoloConfig.args)
```

Here is the dockerFile

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:2.0.1-cuda11.7-cudnn8-runtime

# 显示Python模块路径
RUN python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"

# 检查Python版本
RUN python --version

# Create working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/ultralytics


# 添加整个项目到容器中
COPY . /usr/src/ultralytics

#TODO 或许有用 Set the PYTHONPATH inside the container
#ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/src/ultralytics"
ENV PYTHONPATH=/usr/src/ultralytics

# 打印当前目录
RUN pwd
RUN ls -a

......

# 暴露端口
EXPOSE 5000
# 指定命令
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

This is the previous error reported
Previously I wrote "from detection import yolo_config".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/ultralytics/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    from detection import yolo_config
ImportError: cannot import name 'yolo_config' from 'detection' (/usr/src/ultralytics/detection/__init__.py)
```

Here's the error now

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/ultralytics/app.py", line 10, in <module>
    from detection.yolo_config import YoloConfig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'detection.yolo_config'
```

I've tried using **init**.py and adding PYTHONPATH, but both fail!

Comment: Can you share detection/__init__.py?

Comment: @Danysan __init__.py is Empty file

Comment: I tested this locally and with this Dockerfile and these .py-files this works perfectly both within a docker container and outside of it. How are you building and running the image?

Comment: Also, are there additional steps in the Dockerfile currently hidden in "......" that might be relevant?

Comment: @TeemuRisikko  You are correct, running the above file as per my example will run it. I'm sorry it's my fault, I didn't manage the yolo_config.py file in git, so I couldn't get it after docker packaging in gitaction. Thanks for your willingness to help!

Answer (score 1):

running the above file as per my example will run it. I'm sorry it's my fault, I didn't manage the yolo_config.py file in git, so I couldn't get it after docker packaging in gitaction. Thanks for your willingness to help!